# Cryptic Crossword?

Tags: mathematics, word, crosswords, cryptic-crosswords

*You pick up a discarded newspaper, hoping to satiate your need for puzzles with a cryptic crossword. But as you turn to the page, you feel something is awry – perhaps some elision?*

[image: Cryptic Crossword?]

**Across**
**3.** $F_6,F_7,F_8$ mixed $13\times3$ down${}- \sqrt{12\text{ across}}$
**16.** $3$ squares joined${}- 4$ and half of $3$ down
**12.** A square $6$ under $1$ across
**20a.** Multiple of $268727$ less than a square
**8.** Double $37+1019$a across - a square
**19a.** Code for a Lao $45$b down, head rooted
**21.** Twice $120$a across’ smaller prime factor
**1.** $17$ down${}+ 4163^\text{rd}$  prime
**18.** A square two-thirds of $5$d across
**5d.** Palindrome two-thirds of $1$ across${}+ 2$
**19b.** Multiple of $717$ down${}+ 10  $

**Down**
**3.** $\sqrt{x^{yz_{10}}}$ if $16$ across is $xyz_{10}+2^x,x\in\mathbb{N}$
**15.** The start of $20$a across${} - 10555_7$
**13.** $1$ across${} + 101042$ years ago
**16.** $3$ down reversed${} + 13010+{}$AP joined
**5a.** Undecimal $88840+3$ down
**5b.** Double $97-120$b down reversed${} + 61   $
**20b.** $4$ odd digits, or $5$ with flipped $19$b across
**5c.** A sum with the two summands${} - 4+6! $
**17.** AP joined, or a sum of the first $k$ primes

*AP means Arithmetic Progression (of at least 3 terms)

Joined means concatenated*

*Text transcription of crossword [here](https://pastebin.com/mLVasp2q) or see post source code*

Hints for extraction:

> I wonder why the clue numbers are labelled so weirdly... and what could fill in the blanks on the black spaces?

> Perhaps the clues give a message? If only there were a convenient way to turn numbers into letters...

Comment: Sorry, can't see the grid. Read my profile. Use Cubeupload.

Comment: LaTeX missing space bar perhaps, use backslash+spacebar for displaying LaTeX spacebar

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Sorry, I don't see where the missing spacebar is...

Comment: @Scratch---Cat There is a text transcription of the crossword attached via pastebin in the post or you can click edit/improve this post and see it in the post's source code.

Comment: this has been dormant for a while, any hint? :0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Crossword

> [image]

#### Across Clues

> **3.** 13281 = Mixed 8, 13 and 21 = 13 × 1024 - √961
>
>  **16.** 410 = Joined 2<sup>2</sup>, 1<sup>1</sup>, and 0<sup>2</sup> = Joined 4 and 10 (prefix half of 1024)
>
>  **12.** 961 = 31<sup>2</sup> = 967 - 6
>
>  **20a.** 29557 = 11 × 2687 = 172<sup>2</sup> - 27
>
>  **8.** 3747 = 3737 + 10 = 3796 - 7<sup>2</sup>
>
>  **19a.** 3796 = [Lao Digit Four in Unicode](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/3796) = (√9)796
>
>  **21.** 11 = Twice 1 = smaller prime factor of 29557 (11 × 2687)
>
>  **1.** 967 = 963 + 4 = 163<sup>rd</sup> prime
>
>  **18.** 64 = 8<sup>2</sup> = prefix 2/3 of 646
>
>  **5d.** 646 = Palindrome = 2/3 × (967 + 2)
>
>  **19b.** 973 = 7 × 139 = 963 + 10

#### Down Clues

> **3.** 1024 = √4<sup>10</sup> = 2<sup>10</sup>
>
>  **15.** 285 = 295 - 10 = 555<sub>7</sub>
>
>  **13.** 1977 = 967 + 1010 = **43** years ago!
>
>  **16.** 4331 = 4201 + 130 = 10 + 4321
>
>  **5a.** 1064 = 888<sub>11</sub> = 40 + 1024
>
>  **5b.** 9796 = 9797 - 1 = 9735 + 61
>
>  **20b.** 5379 = 4 odd digits = Joined 5 and 379
>
>  **5c.** 716 = -4 + 720 (*I couldn't match the first clue*)
>
>  **17.** 963 = Joined 9, 6 and 3 = Sum of first 24 primes

However, I don't have any thought about the digits outside the grid. :(

Comment: Nice job! (Sorry I didn't see this, my stackexchange inbox was playing up.) I'm going to post a hint for what the digits outside the grid are.

Answer (score 5):

user65284 has already completed the crossword.

To obtain the final answer first do the following

> Take each of the clue numbers and replace with a letter using the standard alphanumeric cipher (1=A, 2=B, ..., 26=Z). Reading left-to-right top the bottom we get the message **COMPLETETHESQUARES** or, adding spaces, **COMPLETE THE SQUARES**.
>  This suggests that the entries in the black squares should be filled in such a way that reading the numbers which intersect the black squares either down or across should yield a perfect square. To make this work, we need to also incorporate the digits outside the grid in the row or column in which they appear, so for example, the number in the 3rd row is 3XX29557XX0126096 which must be a perfect square when the Xs are filled in.

Under these conditions there is a unique way to complete the grid

> [image]

And finally

> Taking the numbers in the black squares in order and using the alphanumeric cipher once more we find that they spell out **RESPOND**, so that must be the message.

Comment: Nice job - that's correct! Given that user65284 filled in the crossword, I'm going to award them the checkmark: hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @boboquack Yeah, no problem. Nice puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:
5c. A sum with the two summands

> A sum (**7**) with the two summands (**1** and **6**) $= 716 =$ −4+6 !

(The previous answer didn't say this, so l put it here.)

Comment: CAPTCHA popped up again, sorry.